# Android content not resizing after leaving fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a video player and I can make the app go fullscreen just fine but when trying to return to having the navigation and status bar visible the inner content doesn't resize.
I have tried using both the [code](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen) here and [here](https://github.com/ZacSweers/CatchUp/blob/aa1e6b1987f38e8bcfa41c1811fab060bd652b4b/app/src/main/kotlin/io/sweers/catchup/ui/immersive/SystemUiHelperImplJB.kt#L50).

It is a normal `AppCompatActivity`, using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, I have tried messing with the themes, calling `requestLayout()` on the decor view, messing with the `configChanges` flags in the manifest, all to no avail.

I have also tried the code in another pet project of mine and saw the same symptoms.. Not sure what I'm missing but the inner content will not resize to account for the re-shown status and navigation controls.

Comment: could you post you code block where you are using `View.SYSTEM_UI_***`

Comment: Could you post the manifest file where you want to change configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, unsure if there is a cleaner way but I put `fitsSystemWindows` on the ViewPlayer layout and in my activity used this:

```java
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(playerView, (view, insets) -> {
    WindowInsetsCompat windowInsets = insets;

    int systemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    if (systemUiVisible(systemUiVisibility)) {
        ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, windowInsets);
    } else {
        windowInsets = insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
        ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, windowInsets);
    }

    return windowInsets;
});
```

Which handles insetting the layout based on whether the systemUI is visible or not.